# Using refs in laravel blade to pre-check checkboxes

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to use refs in order to take data from my laravel blade, in each row of a foreach loop, and pre-check checkboxes is the values match a checkbox. In this example, if a row in the loop has `$result->site` of intra and `$result->category` of catalog, I would want the intra and catalog checkboxes on that row to be checked.

I'm using refs because I had to do something similar for other data in the rows but I don't know exactly how to apply it to matching the blade value to the id or value of a checkbox and make it checked.

What am I missing here?

```
@foreach($getResults as $k => $result)

    //$result->site and $result->category hold the value I need to match in order to pre-select a checkbox

    <div slot="site" >
        <input category="checkbox" id='direct' value='direct'   ref="existingsiteNames" data-md-icheck  />
        <label>Direct</label><br>
        <input category="checkbox" id='intra' value='intra'  ref="existingsiteNames" data-md-icheck  />
        <label>Intra</label><br>
    </div>

    <div slot="category" >
        <input category="checkbox" id='marketing' value='marketing' ref="existingcategoryNames" data-md-icheck  />
        <label>Marketing</label><br>
        <input category="checkbox" id='catalog' value='catalog' ref="existingcategoryNames" data-md-icheck  />
        <label>Catalog</label><br>
    </div>

    <div slot="footer">
      <button class="modal-save-button" @click="updateHandler">
        Save
      </button>
    </div>
@endforeach

new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data: { 
        showGroupModal: false,
        showAddModal: false,
        existingcategoryNames: [],
        existingsiteNames: [],
    },
    methods: {
        updateHandler(event) {
            this.showGroupModal = false;
            this.updateGroupDetails(event);
        },
        updateGroupDetails: function(event){

            let data = {
                site: this.$refs.existingsiteNames,
                category: this.$refs.existingcategoryNames,
            };

            axios.post('/update', data)
            .then((response) => {
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
            })
            .finally(function () {
            });
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: you only want those inputs to have those 'refs' if they match (would be checked)?

Comment: @lagbox Yes that is correct. The checkboxes are possibilities but I want to check them if the match exists and only have the refs if they are checked

Comment: @lagbox does that make sense?

Comment: @TomN. I'm still not following sorry. So you want to pre-check the checkboxes based on $result.. but what is the purpose of using refs? Generally I have found that there is usually a better solution than using refs, which is why I ask.

Comment: I have a feeling that this is not the use case for `$refs`. But the task needs clarification. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: how are you distinguishing between a checked and unchecked checkbox when using the 'refs'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to check checkboxes based on a condition.
Here's an example took from my own code:

```
<input {{ $something->isAwesome ?: "checked" }} type="checkbox" >
```

In this example, we check if $something is awesome, and if it is we print the string "checked", making the checkbox checked.
If this is not what you wanted to accomplish tell me and i will update answer.

Answer (score 0):

More convenient way for rendering a form is to use Laravel HTML Collective library(https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html)

```
{!! Form::checkbox('catalog', 'catalog', $result->isExistingCategoryNames()) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

## New in laravel9

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#checked-and-selected

The current version of laravel introduced new directives for **input binary attributes** `@checked`, `@selected` and `@disabled`

```html
<input @checked($something->isAwesome) type="checkbox" >
```